# Why is my Path -> Difference not cutting the whole object?

Tags: inkscape, path

Im trying to cutout an object from the background (both are objects/paths). So I am selecting the background object first, shift selecting the foreground object. Then pressing Path -> Difference

As you can see in the images below it's not cutting what I expect. The top portion is not even the same size. Am I missing a critical step??

Pre Difference
[image]

Post-Difference
[image]

Comment: How is the parachute graphic constructed?  It won't work unless it's a compound path. Also strokes won't work.

Comment: The parachute was an image that I took made it a path by going Path -> Object to Path.  So it has nodes and whatnot (Im still new to Inkscape so forgive if I use any wrong terminology), I do not believe it has any strokes because the stroke color and width is set to none and zero respectively.

Comment: If you share the SVG on SVGshare.com I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks! http://svgshare.com/s/TWG

Comment: There's a thick pink stroke on the background rectangle which is the cause of the problem. The thick stroke is obscuring the gaps. Just remove it and everything will work.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try it when I get home!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all strokes. Set stroke color = none. Zero width or fully transparent color is different thing than no color. Select all those green parts and apply Path > Union. That's because only one path can be subtracted at a time.

The target (=red) must also be a single path, but it seems already like it's a single path. It must NOT have a stroke because the stroke fills partially the holes. I guess there's a wide red stroke.

Path > Combine also works instead of Union if there's no overlapping green parts. Subtract then the united green part from the background shape.

Strokes can be converted to filled strokeless paths by applying Path > Stroke to Path. Before it they do not take part in Union, Difference nor other Boolean operations.

Comment: I think this was it, the background (red) had a stroke to it, not the green.